# Make a DataFrame with its values as concatenated index and column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'd like to create a pandas DataFrame with its values as concatenated index and column names. In the example below, I'd have the column name concatenated to the row name; however, a vice versa scenario is also possible.

```
   A      B      C
A  AA     AB     AC
B  BA     BB     BC
C  CA     CB     CC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Numpy's `char` module

We want to use Numpy's broadcasting while using a string specific function.

### Setup

I used an index of `['X', 'Y', 'Z']` to make more obvious that what I'm doing is accurate.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['X', 'Y', 'Z'], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

---

### Solution

```
idx = df.index.to_numpy().astype(str)
col = df.columns.to_numpy().astype(str)

df.loc[:, :] = np.char.add(idx[:, None], col)

df

    A   B   C
X  XA  XB  XC
Y  YA  YB  YC
Z  ZA  ZB  ZC
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to multiply the columns list by the length of `df`; then use `radd` on `axis=0` to concatenate index names from the right:

```
df.loc[:,:] = [df.columns.astype(str).tolist()]*df.shape[0]
df = df.radd(df.index.astype(str), axis=0)
```

Or do the converse by multiplying the index list by the width of `df`; then use `add` on `axis=1` to concatenate the column names:

```
df.loc[:,:] = list(zip(*[df.index.tolist()]*df.shape[1]))
df = df.add(df.columns, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
A  AA  AB  AC
B  BA  BB  BC
C  CA  CB  CC
```

Answer (score 1):

for the provided data example this code do the trick:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.index + x.name)

>>> df
'''
    A   B   C
A  AA  AB  AC
B  BA  BB  BC
C  CA  CB  CC
```